# Error loading Tests - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

Today I merged some fairly large changes to a project into the stable branch. In doing so, I seem to have inadvertently botched some settings related to my unit tests. When I try to run my tests, I get the following message printed to the console:

```
Error loading /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4AEE69C-CC6C-4C56-BCE2-    82EF5A1B4549/tmp/NightRide Tests.xctest/NightRide Tests:      dlopen(/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4AEE69C-CC6C-4C56-BCE2-    82EF5A1B4549/tmp/NightRide Tests.xctest/NightRide Tests, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4AEE69C-CC6C-4C56-BCE2-   82EF5A1B4549/tmp/NightRide Tests.xctest/NightRide Tests: code signature invalid for     '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4AEE69C-CC6C-4C56-BCE2-82EF5A1B4549/tmp/NightRide Tests.xctest/NightRide Tests'
DevToolsBundleInjection: Error loading bundle     '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D4AEE69C-CC6C-4C56-BCE2-82EF5A1B4549/tmp/NightRide Tests.xctest'
```

I honestly don't know what could be causing this. I went back to the branch I merged from, where I know the tests ran just fine yesterday, and I experience the issue there as well. How might I go about fixing this? Is there a build setting somewhere that resolves to this path spit out in the console? What's weird is that it says there was an error loading from that path and then right after that it says "Did find:" the same path it previously had an error loading.